# Custom formatting of float within form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way to control the float format in a form field?

I want to format a float like an integer if the modulus is 0, otherwise display the float as is. I overrode the Model accessor to do this formatting.

When an edit form is loaded, I would like to have the following transformations:

```
stored value | accessor returns | form field shows
---------------------------------------------------
1.0          | 1                | 1
1.5          | 1.5              | 1.5
```

However, form_for appears to be accessing the attribute directly, thereby displaying the float as is.

Any ideas on how to get around this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do believe it will work when you do something like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :field_attribute, :value => format_method(f.object.field_attribute) %>
```

format_method is whatever method you use within the model to override the formatting when accessing it that way.

Comment: I considered doing this early on since it keeps the formatting logic in the view layer, but I thought it might be better to push the formatting into the model so I don't have to duplicate this in views...but I guess that is what partials are for.

I think I'll go with this solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
def my_float
  raw = read_attribute(:my_float)
  if raw == raw.to_i
    raw.to_i
  else
    raw
  end
end
```

within `form_for` will not work as noted before. Tried multiple times. IMHO it is one of more severe design issues with rails. In general you don't have straight forward (restful) access to model from your view.

Answer (score 1):

You could override the attribute reader,  something like  this:

```
def myfloat
  if @myfloat == @myfloat.to_i
    @myfloat.to_i
  else
    @myfloat
  end
end
```

Now the returned value are correctly formatted for your form and still usable in your application.

Comment: Yeah, I already have something like that in my model. But my question was how do I get the form_for to use the overridden attribute reader? It seems to use read_attribute or something.

Comment: I do not think that read_attribute is used. According to 'Overwriting default accessors' in http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html, the method I described should be used when specialized behaviour is required. Which seems to be the case in your situation.

Comment: I wish this would work, but the text_field helper method grabs the value directly (i.e. it does not call the accessor).

Answer (score 0):

[Veger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246263/veger)'s solution will work if you use [`read_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/read_attribute) to get the "raw" value:

```
def myfloat
  raw = read_attribute(:myfloat)
  if raw == raw.to_i
    raw.to_i
  else
    raw
  end
end
```

As always when comparing floats to integers, you'd want to be careful about rounding.

Answer (score 0):

You can override respond_to? in the Model to stop value_before_type_cast from being called.

```
def respond_to?(*args)
  if args.first.to_s == "my_float_before_type_cast"
    false
  else
    super
  end
end
```

And then you need also:

```
def my_float
  raw = read_attribute(:my_float)
  if raw == raw.to_i
    raw.to_i
  else
    raw
  end
end
```